# Table columns data to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I met with some  weird DB design during a data migration, and trying to convert a table data to a more normalized form.
Here employees belongs to various positions and Employee-Position table looks like: `EmpNo, Position1, SalCode1, Position2, SalCode2, Position3, SalCode3, Position4,  SalCode4` etc.

```
EmpNo   Position01  SalCodeS01  Position02  SalCodeS02  Position03  SalCodeS03
E123    EL028       ENADV        EL029        ENADV     BF046       ENADV 
E125    EL028       LHENAD       EL029        LHENAD    BF046       LHENAD
E126    EL049       LHENAD       BF046        LHENAD    BF047       LHENAD
E127    EL028       LHENAD       EL029        LHENAD    BF046       LHENAD
E128    EL028       LHENAD       EL029        LHENAD    BF046       LHENAD
E129    EL049       LHENAD       BF046        LHENAD    BF047       LHENAD
```

Trying to normalize like `EmpNo, Position, SalCode`

```
EmpNo   Position    SalCode
E123    EL028      ENADV      
E123    EL029      ENADV      
E123    BF046      ENADV      
E123    BF047      ENADV      
E125    EL028      LHENAD     
E125    EL029      LHENAD     
E125    BF046      LHENAD     
E125    BF047      LHENAD
```

Is anyone can suggest the best method to accomplish this? Is PIVOT possible? Thanks. 
PS. Please note that I have SELECT permission only and this is one table among 4 tables in a JOIN

Answer (score 1):

may be something like this:

```
select EmpNo, Position01 as Position, SalCodeS01 as SalCode from  employees_table
union
select EmpNo, Position02 as Position, SalCodeS02 as SalCode from  employees_table
union
select EmpNo, Position03 as Position, SalCodeS03 as SalCode from  employees_table
order by EmpNo, Position
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with me is I have other tables to join like EmpAdresses, EmergencyContact details etc. so UNION is difficult

Comment: make a view or a temporary table with unions and then join on it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a procedure to do this task. Define a cursor and for each iteration of the cursor, do this.

```
INSERT INTO employee_positions_new (EmpNo, Position01, SalCodeS01);
INSERT INTO employee_positions_new (EmpNo, Position02, SalCodeS02);
INSERT INTO employee_positions_new (EmpNo, Position03, SalCodeS03);
```

Comment: I have a SELECT permission only so cannot create DB objects apart from select query

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
  (
     EmpNo      VARCHAR(50),
     Position01 VARCHAR(50),
     SalCodeS01 VARCHAR(50),
     Position02 VARCHAR(50),
     SalCodeS02 VARCHAR(50),
     Position03 VARCHAR(50),
     SalCodeS03 VARCHAR(50)
  )

INSERT INTO #temp
            (EmpNo,Position01,SalCodeS01,Position02,
             SalCodeS02,Position03,SalCodeS03)
VALUES      ('E123','EL028','ENADV','EL029',
             'ENADV','BF046','ENADV'),
            ('E125','EL028','LHENAD','EL029',
             'LHENAD','BF046','LHENAD'),
            ('E126','EL049','LHENAD','BF046',
             'LHENAD','BF047','LHENAD')

SELECT A.EmpNo,
       a.Position,
       b.SalCode
FROM   (SELECT empno,
               Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') Position
        FROM   (SELECT empno,
                       Cast ('<M>'
                             + Replace(Position01+','+Position02+','+Position03, ',', '</M><M>')
                             + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
                FROM   #temp) AS A
               CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) A
       JOIN (SELECT empno,
                    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') SalCode
             FROM   (SELECT empno,
                            Cast ('<M>'
                                  + Replace(SalCodeS01+','+SalCodeS02+','+SalCodeS03, ',', '</M><M>')
                                  + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
                     FROM   #temp) AS A
                    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) B
         ON a.EmpNo = b.EmpNo
```

OUTPUT

```
   EmpNo    Position    SalCode
    E123    EL028   ENADV
    E123    EL029   ENADV
    E123    BF046   ENADV
    E123    EL028   ENADV
    E123    EL029   ENADV
    E123    BF046   ENADV
    E123    EL028   ENADV
    E123    EL029   ENADV
    E123    BF046   ENADV
    E125    EL028   LHENAD
    E125    EL029   LHENAD
    E125    BF046   LHENAD
    E125    EL028   LHENAD
    E125    EL029   LHENAD
    E125    BF046   LHENAD
    E125    EL028   LHENAD
    E125    EL029   LHENAD
    E125    BF046   LHENAD
    E126    EL049   LHENAD
    E126    BF046   LHENAD
    E126    BF047   LHENAD
    E126    EL049   LHENAD
    E126    BF046   LHENAD
    .......
```